Мне надо создать форму в которой я указываю ширину и высоту нового изображения
вот форма для создания изображения
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ArtEdit
{
    public partial class Create : Form
    {
        public Bitmap CreatedImage { get; private set; }

        public Create()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int width = int.Parse(domainUpDownWidth.Text);
                int height = int.Parse(domainUpDownHeight.Text);

                // Создание нового изображения с заданными параметрами
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.Clear(Color.White); // Заполнение белым цветом
                }

                // Установка созданного изображения
                CreatedImage = bitmap;

                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Пожалуйста, введите допустимые значения ширины и высоты.", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}

вот метод для вызова этой формы
private void создатьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Create createForm = new Create())
    {
        if(createForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (pictureBox1 != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                pictureBox1.Image = null; // Сбрасываем ссылку на изображение
            }

            Bitmap newImage = createForm.CreatedImage;

            pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}

проблема в том что при указании на форме ширины и высоты и нажатии кнопки ок ничего не происходит остается тоже изображение что и было
только пропадает возможность рисовать на изображении
